# Adjust Vertical Position of a Single Character in InDesign?

Tags: typography, adobe-indesign

I have a paragraph with a rather large line height (38pt), and I need the very last character to be positioned lower than the other characters. Is there a good way to do this without resorting to creating a new text block?

Comment: Simple "how to" questions are off-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Should have read the FAQ since this was my first question. Completely my fault. =)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, guys. Just figured it out. The answer is to give "Baseline Shift" a negative value for the single character in question.